# how to change the page name by using adobe dtm?

Tags: javascript, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

Actually the model page name is incorrectly set under adobe analytics, so i want to change that name to Model detail:Model#.

so how to do it under adobe dynamic tag management.

**Here i am attaching the screenshot, please let me know.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In DTM, the standard practice is to create a Data Element that contains logic for generating the value for a given variable. You do this by navigating to

**`Rules`** `>` **`Data Elements`** `>` **`Create New Data Element`**

[image]

How you configure the **Data Element** depends on where the values for your page name are coming from. You said you want to populate `pageName` with "Model detail:Model#". Where do those values come from? Does your site output a data layer? Within other existing javascript variables to reference? Part of the URL structure? HTML Element(s) on the page to scrape using CSS selectors? The answer to this will determine how you configure the **Data Element**.

From there, the **Name** you give the **Data Element** will then be used as a reference elsewhere with DTM. For example, if you give the **Data Element** a name of `page_name`, you can reference it in DTM **Tool** and **Rule** config fields with `%page_name%`.  Or, you can reference it with javascript syntax in custom code boxes with `_satellite.getVar('page_name')`

Which syntax you should use, and where you should use it, depends on how Adobe Analytics (AA) is implemented on your site. If AA implemented as a **Tool**, you can globally set the `pageName` value in the **Tool** config, under the **Pageviews & Content** section, using the `%page_name%` syntax:

[image]

Or, if you want to create a **Page Load Rule** to only populate it on certain pages based on Conditions, there is similar **Page Name** field in the Adobe Analytics section in the **Page Load Rule**:

[image]

And again, what condition(s) you create to trigger the rule depends on how your site is structured, so you will need to figure that out. For example if you only want it to trigger on product detail pages, and you know all product detail pages are within a `/product/[..]` URL path, you can create a condition based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Great thing about DTM is your ability to manipulate data values before they get sent to Adobe for processing. In the case of manipulating the pageName to Model detail:Model#, there are a number of ways to manipulate pageName (or any other variable).

Crayon does a nice job above explaining the best practice of using data elements. In addition, you can add JavaScript to the custom code section at the rule level to force data changes:

**Use Case:** You have a global page load rule (set on all pages) that uses a data layer as the source for variable mapping.

1. Within the global page load rule, you can manipulate data and variables based on condition.[image: Custom Code under Adobe Analytics Section]

   ```
   if(digitalData.pageData.pageName == "Model detail"){
   s.pageName = "Model detail:Model#";

   }
   ```

You can also update an individual element within a very specific rule.

**Use Case**: You have a single rule with a specific condition for the homepage based on URL:

1. Within the Adobe Analytics variable section you can add the value of the home page you need to pageName:

   [image: Adobe Analytics section of homepage rule]

This method is not a recommended best practice because it is not dynamic and requires "hard-coding" values. However, if you need to make a quick change to a specific element within a rule, this is one way to do it.

DTM allows you to manipulate data using a number of methods. Hope this helps.